# QML: What does i18n.tr("blah blah blah") mean?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Specifically, what is i18n.tr short for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `i18n` portion is the component name, and the `tr()` function is the function to translate a string, in the Ubuntu SDK, with QML.

[This method of translation support](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.i18n/) uses gettext, and not the built-in localization features of Qt/QML, which are not compatible with gettext.

Comment: what is the significance of "i + 18 + n"?

Comment: The terms are frequently abbreviated to the numeronyms i18n (where 18 stands for the number of letters between the first i and last n in internationalization, a usage coined at DEC in the 1970s or 80s) See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)